# Windows batch script to change names with some logic

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory with the following layout:

```
1 януари 2012
2 февруари 2012
1 януари 2013
```

And I want it to look like this `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
2012-01-01
2012-02-01
2013-01-01
```

**Януари / февруари** are Cyrillic names of months so they map easily to numbers - **01 / 02**.

The script basically has to:

1. take a dir name
2. rename it in the correct format

I am very new to batch script coding.

So if you could help me it would be great.

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service! You must show your own efforts if you expect help! Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, you need to rename only folders for *януари* and *февруари*, replace *C:\Folders* with real full path to your target directory, save this script to *test.bat*, open Cmd Prompt from the script folder, and test it. It works well for me in Win10 English with your dir names regardless of the current Cmd codepage.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "dir=C:\Folders"
for /f "tokens=4" %%A in ('chcp') do (
    if not %%A==855 set "enc=%%A" & chcp 855 >nul)
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%G in ('dir /b /a:d "%dir%"') do (
    set "yea=%%I" & set "fold=%%G %%H %%I"
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=я" %%B in ("%%H") do (
        if not %%C.==. (set  mon=01) else set mon=02)
    if %%G leq 9 (set dat=0%%G) else set dat=%%G
    set "nfold=!yea!-!mon!-!dat!"
    move /y "%dir%\!fold!" "%dir%\!nfold!"
)
if defined enc chcp !enc! >nul
exit /b
```

Comment: it gives me "File Not Found" ?

Comment: sorry - the real error is "The system cannot find the file specified." which comes from line " move /y "%dir%\!fold!" "%dir%\!nfold!"" ?

Comment: adding     echo !fold!; echo !nfold! before the move gives the following output https://postimg.org/image/kvz3enzjv/

Comment: Try changing Cmd codepage http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html to your OS language in the code, like chcp 852 instead of 855.

Comment: I tried with all of the availabel chcp-s but for some reason it did not work

Comment: Try changing Font in Cmd Console Properties to Lucida Console or such. It may be, the font currently selected doesn't support characters of your selected Cmd Codepage. Also, make sure support for your language is added in Windows Language Prefs (I see it is already looking at Win Explorer in your pic). Your pic shows, current console font or codepage doesn't support your native language. Research on the web, what console fonts and codepage support your language.